# It is possible for the text size to decrease automatically on browser resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've set my page font to `font-size: 0.6875em;` now I was wondering, seeing as I've used percentages for the widths and padding for all my DIVS will my text size reduce like my DIVS when I resize the browser by dragging the window (not with a JavaScript function)?

It seems not! I know I can add CSS media queries and there's probably a JavaScript / jQuery tool for this but can I auto decrease my text size when the user drags the corner of the browser and reduces (or increases) the size of the window or must I use JS / CSS media queries?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `em` is always a relative unit, based on the font size (usually based on the inherited font-size). If you want something the always scales, use a different unit (but it's almost certainly the wrong thing to do - if someone reduces the viewport to 1/4 of its size, they don't tend to expect the text to reduce also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) { body { font-size:12px; }}
```

Here, when browser size becomes at least `640` or below, font size will be 12px.

You need to adjust `min-width` and CSS selector as per your requirement.

Note that you can have multiple media queries for different sizes.

More Info:

- http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/

Comment: But do I have to? Will the text not automatically change size as the DIVs do?

Comment: @MikeSav: Yes it will when browser size will be smaller which you specify in `min-width` as i have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible without JS/media queries. Percentages always apply to the inherited/initial font size.

Comment: Can I set the font size to a percentage instead of ems or do I just have to bit the bullet and use JS/media queries?

Comment: Sorry, I was not being clear. I meant to say that it is possible to set a percentage as a font size, but this percentage does not refer to any widths or heights, but to the parent's font size. Which means it is constant, so that's no use.